# Could you estimate the rate of reaction from the chemical structure of the reactants? If so, how?

Tags: theoretical-chemistry

Say you have two compounds with their own unique chemical structures and you know the environment (e.g. temperature, pressure, presence of enzymes) could you then, using this information, approximate the rate of reaction? And if so, how would you? Please provide a mathematical answer, not just use some software.

Comment: Are you looking for an academic/theoretical answer, or are you interested in concrete practical methods (i.e., modeling software, crude back-of-the-envelope calculations, etc.)? I'm aware of software suites that can simulate certain classes of reactions, but if you're looking for an exact rate equation to model something other than an elementary mechanistic step, then I suspect you're out of luck (even in those instances, the rate constant of the equation has to be determined experimentally [or approximated computationally] and potentially varies with multiple parameters).

Comment: A mathematical model, i.e. an academic/theoretical answer. I knew this would be a tricky question, especially since from what I can tell most chemists know hardly any math beyond the basics, but still I'm a mathematician and if someone knows the answer that'll be much appreciated.

Comment: theoretically it is possible, but will require  scan of potential energy surface near reaction path. After this, using molecular dynamics it is possible to scan over reaction path and say, how many collisions of which energy will result in reaction. With this, you will be able to estimate speed of reaction at any reasonable temperature. This task, however, is extremely calculation intensive and unlikely to be pragmatic, so it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Permeakra's answer is good, as are the ones by Home and Greg E.  But the sad truth is that in general the answer to the question is NO, you cannot estimate the rate of the reaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul J. Gans correctly pointed out in his comment, in general it is impossible.

In practice you can calculate reaction rates only for quite restrictive class of reactions - the *unimolecular gas-phase* reactions - using *RRKM theory*.
The whole potential energy surface is actually not needed, as far as I know, you just need to identify reactant, product, and transition state.
RRKM is based on few assumptions, with the first one being quite obvious: since we are talking about potential energy surfaces, the electronic motion and the nuclear motion is separated by the Born-Oppenheimer approximation.
The nuclear motion is also assumed to be well separated into rotational, vibrational, and translational one. The internal degrees of freedom are treated classically with quantum mechanical corrections.

RRKM is quite useful for predicting gas phase dissociation and isomerization rates  under low pressure (low enough so that reaction can be safely assumed to be unimolecular). For that reason, this theory is ofthen used in mass-spectrometry, since the above mentioned conditions are quite often met here, but it is of no use for reactions in the condensed phase.